# How to call function jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wanna callback jQuery function

```
$(function upload() {
.....
});

$("#select").change(function() {
    upload();
});
```

Console
Uncaught ReferenceError: upload is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You have actually provided a named callback to the shortcut DOM ready event handler. You need to declare it globally (or in the same scope).

This example has them in the same scope:

```
$(function(){  // DOM ready handler
    function upload() {

    };

    $("#select").change(function() {
        upload();
    });
});
```

As the function has no parameters it abbreviates to:

```
$(function(){  // DOM ready handler
    function upload() {

    };

    $("#select").change(upload);
});
```

The cleaner way (if the function is not reused) is just to place the code in the `change` callback:

```
$(function(){
    $("#select").change(function() {
        // Do the upload code here instead
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is inside a closure and therefore not global. Remove that `$` wrapping and everything should be fine.

```
function upload() {
   // (...) code
}
$("#select").change(function() {
    upload();
})
```

Or put the `<select>` code inside the DOM ready wrapper. It should work too. Or declare it like

```
window.upload = function(){
  // this is global
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : define a function `upload` inside `$(function(){  });` and call it inside `change` event handler of `select` box.

```
$(function(){
  //define function
  upload = function(){
  ....
  }

  $("#select").change(function() {
    //call function
    upload();
  });
});
```

Comment: Actually your `Note` is incorrect. So long as it is defined in the same scope it will exist. Also it only needs to be defined before it is actually called. Javascript only checks at call-time :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, yeah you are correct.. I removed my `note`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put ("#select").change inside Ready function and upload function outside ready function.

```
function upload() {
// any thing you want to do after select
};

$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#select").change(function() {
upload();
})

});
```